# Mouse stops clicking after using wacom tablet in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse, wacom, lockup

I have a pretty old wacom tablet; a graphire 4 and it seemed to work well but I've encountered a problem where I start using it in photoshop, gimp or MyPaint (or even just hovering the stylus over, I believe.) and suddenly after a while, but most of the time immediately, I can't click anywhere on the screen. nothing responds and that goes for the normal mouse as well.

sometimes I will notice that the hover effects on docks and other stuff are still active and my short-cut keys for my keyboard still work so I know the system is not locked up.
I've tried restarting unity and compiz and it fixes the problem for about 5 seconds before the mouse stops working again even without using the tablet.
The only solution so far is to reboot and not use the tablet.

This is a really important thing for me so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's possible you have this bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/782756

Comment: My buttons and scrolling wheel don’t work at all, the only thing that worked fine for a while was my stylus and the pressure sensitivity worked perfectly. that's all I cared about.
Might be related but I don’t see how.
But thank you :)

Comment: That bug fix is included with Ubuntu Kernel version ubuntu-11.10 (and later) supposedly.  You tagged it 12.04 but to check: lsb_release -a or cat /etc/issue from command line should tell you the version.  To hopefully get an idea of what is going on hit ctrl + alt + f1 and run sudo tail -f /var/log/apport.log before you start using the tablet.  Then hit ctrl + alt + f7 and when it crashes go back to ctrl + alt + f1 to see any relevant errors and report them here.  tail -f will show changes to a file real time. (-f means follow, tail grabs the end of the file).